# Local copy of MathJax on a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I´m using the new Jupyter notebook (neé ipython notebook) and the docs indicate that it renders MathJax from a CDN. I have some situations when outside connections are blocked, so I need to configure a local copy of MathJax for all notebooks. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 9):

> As of 4.0 mathjax is part of the notebook as a dependency. There is no need for any extra installation.

I am currently experimenting with jupyter on a RaspberryPi. After installation of python 3.4 and jupyter I found MathJax in:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax

from my jupyter_notebook_config.py file:

```
# c.NotebookApp.mathjax_url = ''
c.NotebookApp.enable_mathjax = True
```

Credits go to @minrk who clarified this to me!

Answer (score 9):

On Arch Linux, installing 'community/mathjax' solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Open any notebook and write:
`From IPython.external import mathjax`

Then you can read how to install by writing: '`mathjax?`' but basically you execute a function '`install_mathjax()`'. Haven't tried it though.